# setTimeout in Complex / time consuming operation Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, settimeout

I have a complex function named, BookMarkReplacementAndPrint(). This function opens the Word document from the Server, on the client's browser using activex. And replaces
the book marks, and sends the print command to the printer to print the document.
There are couple of operations which is very time consuming, like opening the documents, replacing book marks. I have marked those piece of code.

Now at the same time on the UI I need to display the progress of the activity, by updating textarea, and there is a "Close" button to close the operation. 
The problem is my UI is not responsive once it starts.

How to make my UI responsive? I tried with setTimeout(), after each TimeConsuming tasks. But still of less use. Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance......

```
var bookMarks = new Array(); 
bookMarks[0]="txtCustAllTLName";       
bookMarks[1]="txtAccountType";
bookMarks[2]="txtAcntNbr";
bookMarks[3]="dteFulfilmentCreated";


var bookMarksValue = new Array(); 
bookMarksValue[0]="Sample Name";       
bookMarksValue[1]="Savings";
bookMarksValue[2]="XXXXX5804";
bookMarksValue[3]="22/01/2008";
function BookMarkReplacementAndPrint()
{
 for (i=0;i<30;i++)
 {
     try{

      var empty;
      var doc = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application"); // creates the word object
      var sDocPath = "http://localhost:8080/bm1.doc";
      doc.Visible=false; // doesn't display Word window

      LOG('Opening the document file');

      //............Time consuming........................................
      // Open the document
      var oDoc = doc.Documents.Open(sDocPath, false, true);
      // .................................................................

      doc.ActivePrinter = "Printer Name";
      doc.Options.PrintBackground = true;

      //............Time consuming.......................................
      // Replacing the Bookmarks.
     for (i=0;i<bookMarks.length;i++)
     {
          LOG("Book Mark Name: "+bookMarks[i] + " " + "Book Mark Value: "+ bookMarksValue[i]);
          DisplayTextInfo('Book Mark Name: "+bookMarks[i] + " " + "Book Mark Value: '+ bookMarksValue[i]);
          var selection = doc.Selection.GoTo(-1,empty,0,bookMarks[i]);
          doc.Selection.TypeText(bookMarksValue[i]);
     }
      // .................................................................

     // Send to Printer
       /* Start Printing */
      doc.ActiveDocument.PrintOut();
      var textArea =  document.getElementById('myarea');
          textArea.innerHTML += "Printed document  "+ i + "\n";
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }
    finally
    {  doc.quit(0); // quit word (very important or you'll quickly chew up memory!)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like BookMarkReplacementAndPrint is synchronous (blocks the UI). Using setTimeout will run it asynchronously, but without a callback function, you can't really send progress back to the UI. Try sending a callback function of some sort to BookMarkReplacementAndPrint that updates the UI.

Comment: You could break down the workflow into parts and call each part using *setTimeout* from the previous part. In the space between each call, update the UI, e.g. `setTimeout(partOne, 0)` and *partOne* ends with `updatUI('partOne');setTimeout(partTwo, 0);` and so on. You could put the sequence of functions in an array and use a controller that keeps track and calls them in sequence. Each function ends by calling the controller to let it know to call the next function or end. There are likely frameworks setup to do this already.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the vital suggestion. Can you please suggest me the better frameworks to achieve this, rather than creating one?